# How to set size of jpanel in null layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Hi I am trying to set the size of  JPanel in JFrame but I am unable to achieve this. How can I achieve my desired output?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Sample extends JFrame 
{ 
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel label1;
public Sample() 
{ 
    panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
    panel.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("E:\\image\\ZooDelhi\\1.jpg"); 
    label1 = new JLabel(icon1); 
    label1.setLocation(0,0); 
    panel.add(label1);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    this.setSize(500,500); 
    this.setVisible(true); 
  setLayout(null);
} 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Sample(); 
} 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: never use `null` layout.

Comment: Swing GUIs might have to work on different platforms, using different PLAFs, on different screen sizes and resolutions with different default settings for font size.  As such, they are **not** conducive to exact placement of components.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) as well as [layout padding and borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556) for white space.

Comment: what is your desired output? share it.

Comment: @Braj i want to set jpanel on my specific position

Comment: what about if system resolution is changed or OS is changed.

Comment: i have to use this application on  single pc

Comment: Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you don't control the properties that change the space components need, such as DPI, font metrics, resolution and other rendering pipeline constraints. While you "might think" you don't need a layout manager, you will spend more time trying to solve problems without them, as Swing has been designed at it's core to utilise them. You will also have issues with the frame borders, which are variable across platforms which will make it difficult to get the window the right size

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of how the GUI should appear at default size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it doesn't matter if you have layout or don't. Not having layout wouldn't harm changing size of JPanel.
Try to use this:

```
myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
```

I hope it'll help ;)

Comment: preferred size is nothing with null layout. LayoutManagers ask for preferred size.

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

**i will advise not to re-size your panel**

If you just use the layout managers correctly, they will take care of panel sizes. To avoid having your components stretched out all over the screen when the user increases the window size, have an outermost panel with a left-aligned FlowLayout and the rest of the UI as its single child - that will give the UI its preferred size and any surplus is filled with the background color.
Check reference to understand more.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Answer (score -1):

Per the Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

1. Set the container's layout manager to null by calling
   setLayout(null).
2. Call the Component class's setbounds method for
   each of the container's children.
3. Call the Component class's
   repaint method.

SUGGESTION: try calling "setLayout(null)" *first*.

Also try looking at the sample code in the link above.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: How Can i can u give small example

Comment: The Oracle link gives a small example - try it!